# Internal Windows powershell error. Failed 80070002

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

I have a Windows 2008 R2 SP1 server with all current windows updates.
I am attempting to run PowerShell but it gives the following error:

> Internal Windows PowerShell error. Loading managed Windows PowerShell
>   failed with error 80070002

It then promptly goes back to the cmd line.

I have run a `sfc /scannow` and it has come back clean.

I have tried running `powershell -noprofile`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling [Windows Management Framework 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855) (KB2819745) resolved the error.

Answer (score 6):

I used this script to test all the .NET folders

```
@echo off
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL
for /D %%z in (*) do (
  echo %%z
  rename %%z %%z1
  powershell 'powershell works'
  rename %%z1 %%z
  pause
  echo.
)
```

Out of 236 folders, the only one that gave me error 80070002 was

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost
```

You can repair PowerShell likes this

```
wusa /extract:. Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg.msu
dism /online /remove-package /packagepath:Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64.cab
dism /online /add-package    /packagepath:Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64.cab
```